# Run 32bit app nn ubuntu 20.04 docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I built a ubuntu image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Disable Prompt During Packages Installation
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Add 32bit architecture
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 

ENV LANG en_US.utf8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    iputils-ping \
    python3 python3-pip

# Copy app to container
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt 


# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["bash"]
```

I've been trying to run a 32bit app (hence the first run command in the Dockerfile) I have inside the my_app directory using:

```
./app
```

but I keep getting

```
bash: ./app: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is that specific to a 32-bit executable? In any case, this needs a [mcve]. Are Ubuntu, 32-bit, Python, Bash, PIP, ping or even `arbe_PhoenixControl` even relevant parts or just randomly present parts that could be removed?

Comment: I fixed it, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I build your docker file with no error, do you have more detail ?

Comment: That is not an answer but a comment. Don't post it as answer. Caveat: I'm unsure if you actually _can_ post comments yet. Sorry if that's not the case.

Comment: I am also able to build the dockerfile with no errors but I am still getting the 'bash: ./app: No such file or directory' error when trying to run my 32bit app.